# Visual studio 2008 Code snippets are not working and not showing in intellisense

Tags: visual-studio-2008, intellisense, code-snippets

I'm having an issue where none of my code snippets are working and they aren't showing up in intellisense.

> 1.Switch, prop and all other snippets aren't listed in intellisense.
>
> 2.When I try to use  shift+alt+f10 to generate a method stub, I get an error:
>
> > "code snippet titled [Method Stub - Body] failed to load. Verify that the refactoring snippets are recognized in the code snippet manager and that the snippet files are valid on disk."

The [method stub - body] snippet is in the snippet manager (I can see it listed) and I opened the file in XML editor and validated it. I've reset VS settings. Rebooted, restarted VS2008, removed all add-ins, I've removed and re-added the paths for the VC# "refactoring" folder within the Code Snippet Manager. I'm out of ideas (well, the last one being re-install). Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Someone else logged into my computer and tested this. The code snippets worked under his login. This proved that the issue was a profile setting. I fixed this by doing two things:

- I renamed the 9.0 folder to 9.0_test (because I didn't want to delete it just yet) found in Application Data and in Local Settings.

  - D:\documents and settings\'your user name'\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0
  - D:\documents and settings\'your user name'\Local Settings\Application Data\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0

I then fired up VS2008 and tested snippets. Everything worked fine.